# GWT SelectionModel in Cell widgets - setSelected by key?

Tags: gwt

Is there any way to select items by key with GWT's selection model?  `setSelected` only seems to take an object from which it can derive a Key, but using that function means I have to construct a sort of fake object.  If my KeyProvider ever changes, that part of my code could break without my knowledge, so I'd like to just construct a key directly somehow.

Comment: Hmm. I am not sure I understand correctly. What do you mean with key? Maybe you can provide an example.

Comment: I have a celltable that shows a list of entities.  When the user creates a new entity, I want to refresh the list (which will have the new entity) and automatically select the new entity.  Now, I don't know which one the new entity is... all I know is the id of the new entity (returned from server).  So, I want to say, "Hey CellTable, select the entity with id #1234," instead of making a fake object with the correct id and telling it to select that (same effect, but with crappy empty-field side effects when I call `getSelected()`)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Now i understand the issue. I never really had that usecase before. I am not sure how to solve it. I assume the type for the CellTable is your Object (CellTable<someClass>). It seems that also SelectionModel and ProvidesKey have to use that same type. I am not sure if it is possible to subclass CellTable, seletionModel to support selecting by a key. Alternatively you could use a helper function to iterate through your list and return the object with the specified key (but that's probably a ugly hack). I am curious if somebody has a solution for that issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"I have a celltable that shows a list of entities. When the user creates a new entity, I want to refresh the list (which will have the new entity) and automatically select the new entity."

I have this behaviour in my app as well.  I manipulate the ListDataProvider.  I find the item or items of interest, move them to the top of the list, call the selection model to set them to selected, and refresh the attached data displays.  I use the same approach for picklist tables I use when I want to pre-select the default choices for the user (usually based on the item that is spawning the picklist) and move them to the top of the list.  I spent a lot of time looking through the selection model api and there is nothing for keys.  I suspect that the GWT designers figured it wasn't necessary, since you have access to the ListDataProvider.  Find the items of interest there and then call the selection model select method on those specific objects.  I can see their point -- replicating the functionality in ListDataProvider and SelectionModel would blur the distinction between the two classes, and perhaps limit the reusability of the SelectionModel construction in other (future) data structures that don't use keys.

Comment: I suspect this is the best solution, and you have a point - the SelectionModel ought not have to query the data in the general case.  Thanks for your thoughts!